# Can't change font color or make text-decoration none to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, navbar

Here's my HTML code of a `navbar`, I'm trying to select CSS selectors to make the font of my LI a different color and also remove `text-decoration`, both that don't work when I select `.navlinks li` or `.navbarcontainer .option`. Conceptually what am I missing here and what is the right answer?

```
<nav>
  <div class="navbarcontainer">
    <ul class = "navlinks"> 
      <div class="left">
      <li class = option><a href="#"> About</a></li>
      <li class = option><a href="#"> Store</a></li></div>
      <div class="right">
      <li class = option ><a href="#"> Gmail</a></li>
      <li class = option ><a href="#"> Images</a></li>
      <li class = option ><a href="#"> Logo</a></li>
      <li class = option ><a href="#"> My Image</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

```
.navbarcontainer {
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;

}

.navlinks {
  display:flex; 
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
  
}

.right {
  margin-left:auto
}
.navlinks li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size:14px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 4px;
  font: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: To change the color, you need to use `color` property. `font` is a shorthand for `font-*` properties

Comment: I would start by fixing the invalid HTML. Only `<li>` should be direct child of an `<ul>`, but you have `<div>`'s as children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text-decoration property should be applied to the anchor tag .
To change the color of the text, use the color property. The font property is a short hand for:

- font-style
- font-variant
- font-weight
- font-size/line-height
- font-family

Note that the color property is not included.

The final css should look like this:

```
.navlinks li {
   list-style-type: none;
   font-size:14px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 4px;
   display: inline-block;
}
.navlinks li a {
   color: red;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tag not selected:
Select "a" inside li

```
.navlinks li a{
  color: red; //for font color
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbarcontainer {
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;

}

.navlinks {
  display:flex; 
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
  
}

.navlinks li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size:14px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navlinks li a{
  color:red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navlinks li
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navbarcontainer">
    <ul class = "navlinks float-left"> 
      <li class = option><a href="#"> About</a></li>
      <li class = option><a href="#"> Store</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class = "navlinks float-right">       
      <li class = option ><a href="#"> Gmail</a></li>
      <li class = option ><a href="#"> Images</a></li>
      <li class = option ><a href="#"> Logo</a></li>
      <li class = option ><a href="#"> My Image</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

Please try this
give style to `li a`.